# Can't post a JSON using $.ajax() or can't read it using php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I can't figure out where the problem is. 
This is my JS function to post the JSON:

```
function send(var1, var2) {
    var result;
    att = window.location;
    $.ajax({
        'crossDomain': true,
        'type': 'POST',
        'async': false,
        'global': false,
        'data': {
            "event_id": var1,
            "status": var2
        },
        'url': att + 'post.php',
        'dataType': 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            result = data['result'];
        }
    });
}
```

On the server side, this (file: post.php):

```php
<?php
    echo $_POST;
?>
```

only prints "Array".
The problem is that I have to send "data" in that exact format (I can't stringify it and then use the php json_decode() function). I also tried the « file_get_contents("php://input") » way, but still nothing.
I don't understand if the problem is that I can't properly post the json or that I'm not able to read it php-side.
Experiments with the GET method were fine.
Sorry for my bad english and thanks everyone for the attention.

Comment: this happend to be today, it seems to happen if the var1, var2 is `undefined`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but sadly if i change "data" to this:
'data' : {"event_id": 'value1',"status": 'value2'},
nothing changes :(

Comment: try `var_dump($post);` ... `echo` does not work for arrays the way you are thinking. Also, can you verify (through firebug) that the data is properly being posted?

Comment: Can you link to a live example? Are you sure that the arguments have valid values? BTW, you can use a relative URL for the AJAX call.

Comment: I don't think is a JSON problem. I just can't post anything. This: function send(var1, var2) {
 var result;
 alert(var1);
 att = window.location;
 $.ajax({
  url: att + 'post.php',
  type: 'POST',
  data: 'something',
  success: function(data){
      }
 });
}
doesn't work. The function $.post() doesn't work either. What can be the problem? Apache?

Comment: NEWS: I can actually post things and read them in php, if I use an html form: <form method="post" action="login.php">
VALUE: <input type="text" name="value">
<input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>. So $.ajax() must be the problem.

Comment: You are not sending JSON this way, you are sending form-encoded data: `event_id=var1&status=var2`. Try serializing data to JSON before the request, setting `processData` to `false` and setting `contentType` to `application/json` (`dataType` is related to data you receive, not the data you send).

Answer (score 0):

To print `array` you can make use of `print_r()` function in php

```
<?php
print_r(json_encode($_POST)); //use json_encode() since dataType in ajax call is json
?>
```

To print individual values, you can make use of `echo()`

```
<?php
 echo(json_encode($_POST['event_id']));
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
In this way it just prints "[]". I fear that $_POST is still empty.

Comment: yes! Post values are not sent to server side. Before ajax call, do an `alert(var1);` to check

Comment: alert(var1) and alert(var2) work properly :( also, even if i change "data" to this: 'data' : {"event_id": 'value1',"status": 'value2'}, nothing changes :(
I'm trying all this on localhost (127.0.0.1), can this mean something? Experiments with the GET method work fine.

Comment: try removing the single quotes. $.ajax({
        crossDomain: true,
        type:'POST',              
        async: false,
        global: false,
        data : {event_id: var1,status:var2},
        url: att + 'post.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    });

Comment: are you including `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script> `

Comment: Yes. I just tried to post things via html form and it works fine, so the problem is definetly in the ajax function.

Comment: ok. Then lets narrow it down. May be some setting in ajax is preventing. try this basic script `$.ajax({ type:'POST',url: 'http://yousite.com/post.php', data : {event_id: var1,status:var2}, dataType: 'json', success: function(data){ alert(data); } }); ` Then in the network tab(firefox:F12, chrome: shft+ctrl+I) check whether the parameters are sent correctly to the script.

Comment: Ok. It posts successfully: POST post.php, Status 200 OK, Dimension 100 B, the exact same thing that says if I press the html form button. But if I then go to /post.php page, $_POST is still empty.
It's like it doesn't save the values: it successfully takes the post and then reset the variable. Using the html form, the values "remain" in $_POST.

Comment: I manually wrote the code and checked it. I created a dummy page "page1" and sent a ajax call to page2 and got the response. This is the link http://pastebin.com/qSj55uPu

Answer (score 0):

try the following js function :

```
function send(var1,var2) {
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $.ajax(
      {
              url:"post.php",
        data:{event_id: var1,status: var2},
        success:function (data, textStatus){
          alert(data['status']);
        }, 
        type:"post",
                dataType: 'json'
      }
      );   
    }); 
}
```

and in server side "post.php" :

```
echo json_encode($_POST);
```